# When $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ holomorphe for $f,g$ holomorphic. What's wrong in my proof ? (exam question)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kz^k$ and $g(z)=\sum_{k=p}^\infty b_kz^k$. I have to stud when $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is holomorphic (in a neighborhood of $0$). This is what I did :

- If $m\geq p$, then $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{b_p+o(1)}\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kz^{k-p},$$
  and thus $\frac{f}{z}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$.
- If $m<p$ then $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{b_p+o(1)}\left(\frac{a_m}{z^{p-m}}+\frac{a_{m-1}}{z^{p-m-1}}+...\right),$$
  and thus we have a pole of order $p-m$.

This was an exam question and I have 5/30. The teacher told me that my proof is not valid because  for example, if $m\geq p$, $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{b_p+o(1)}\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kz^{k-p},$$ is a priori not holomorphic at $0$, but something as $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{b_p+b_{p+1}z+o(z)}\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kz^{k-p},$$ would gave all points.

I feel a bit like the teacher really exaggerated, and even if I made this small mistake, 5/30 is really to low because the idea was here. What do you think ?

Comment: I think that your professor may expect you to write $\dfrac1{b_p+o(1)}$ explicitly as a power series. And, by the way, your $o(1)$ is actually $O(1)$; that is actually a substantive error.

Comment: @TedShifrin : as far as $m\neq p$, this is no problem at all (as I explained in my answer).

Comment: @Surb: I disagree. And I taught complex analysis (both undergraduate and graduate levels) numerous times.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Could you explain please ? I'm maybe wrong, but since (if $m>p$) then $\frac{1}{b_p+o(1)}\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_kz^{k-p}=\frac{a_m}{b_p}z+o(z)$ this should be enough to prove differentiability, no ?

Answer (score 1):

- Your mistake is quite subtly (and as a corrector, I would indeed have given all points since I didn't really see it until you mentioned a mistake). For $m>p$, your proof would have been correct, but it's true that for $m=p$ you only proved that $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{a_m}{b_p}+o(1),$$
  which only prove the continuity but not the differentiability at $0$. But if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ and that $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ has a limit at $0$ then $\frac{f}{g}$ is obviously holomorphic at $0$ as you "almost" proved.
- If $m>p$ you automatically have $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{a_m}{b_p}z+o(z),$$
  what automatically proves the differentiability in a neighborhood of $0$.
- For $m<p$, you proved that $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{a_m}{b_p}\frac{1}{z^{m-p}}+o\left(\frac{1}{z^{m-p}}\right),$$
  what is indeed enough to prove that you have a Pole of order $m-p$, so no mistakes here. Your teacher is very very strict (or stupid). At the end, the mistake only holds when $m=p$, so I can imagine that at least $20/30$ would have been reasonable (since 2 cases on 3 are corrects)... After, I don't know what your teacher expected...

Comment: You mean $z^{m-p}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: yes, thank you :-)